# When will I get charged on my EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, billing

I have set up a Minecraft server on an AWS EC2 instance. My question is, will I get billed for every hour that this EC2 instance is running, or only for when users are connected to the instance?

For example,
The cost of my instance is $0.05/hour. 
There are 732 max billable hours in the month. 
That would make the price of one instance, $33.97.

So my question is, will I be charged the full number of hours as long as the server is running? Or can I request that the server (instance) only boot when players are connected to the IP?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You pay by the time instance is running plus some extras for EBS volumes and egress traffic. An instance is charged on per-second with a minimum of one minute or by the hour.

So, doesn't matter the users and connections. Only the fact that the instance is running.

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/

**UPD:** Per-second billing is available only for Amazon Linux and Ubuntu instances. Other instance types are priced by the hour.

Comment: The per-second billing part is only for Linux instances

Comment: It's literally from the link you shared :) "Pricing is per instance-hour consumed for each instance, from the time an instance is launched until it is terminated or stopped. Each partial instance-hour consumed will be billed per-second for Linux Instances and as a full hour for all other instance types"

Comment: Good point. Thanks! Only Amazon Linux and Ubuntu-based instances are per-second. I'll update the answer.